# jQuery DataTable creating issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datatable

I need to fill DIV container, i.e. create a table using [jQuery DataTable](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html). The problem is that this example does not work for me. Instead of formatted table I see the unformatted one without any element of jQuery DataTable plugin.

The below shown php file is located in folder `main/tables`, while all scripts are located in `main/scripts/media`.

So, what is actually wrong in my code?

```
<?php
    include_once 'include/DatabaseConnector.php';
    $query2="SELECT * FROM resources;";
    $result2=DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQueryArray($query2);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/media/js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/media/js/complete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/media/jsjquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
</script>

<div>
<h1>Employees</h1>

    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <div class="scrollbar">
                <table id="example" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width = "100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Reg</th>
                        <th scope="col">Title</th>
                        <th scope="col">Availability</th>
                        <th scope="col">Latitude</th>
                        <th scope="col">Longitude</th>
                        <th scope="col">Average Speed (km/h)</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($result2 as $row):?>
                        <tr class="alternate">
                        <td><?php echo $row['resReg']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['resTitle']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['resAvailability'] ? 'Yes' : 'No';?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['resLatitude']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['resLongitude']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['resAvgSpeed']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried including the datatables CSS?

Comment: Yes,I tried. Nothing has changed.

Comment: What's the difference between `jsjquery.dataTables.js` and `jquery.dataTables.min.js`? Are they both a copy of the datatables plugin?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the css file. Add it and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add in main jquery file. Like;

`<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

*jQuery UI is not the same as the jQuery library file.
And check whether these two files are duplicate or not. If so, you need only one.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/media/jsjquery.dataTables.js"></script>`